# How can I extract the time for specific percentiles in ggcuminc plot?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am plotting the cumulative incidence function (CIF) and I want to be able to see the time at specific percentiles.

This is my code. I am using the tidycmprsk package and then adding the ggcuming to plot the CIF:

```
cif_RFS_overall <- tidycmprsk::cuminc(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = df) %>%  
  ggcuminc(outcome = "relapse") +
  labs(
    x = "Months"
  ) + 
  add_risktable(risktable_stats = "n.risk") +  
  scale_ggsurvfit()
```

How can I for example get the time for percentile 50% or for 10%?

Comment: Try adding `add_quantile(y_value = .1)` to get a dashed line for 10% cumulative incidence and lines to the corresponding time

Comment: @Ben post as an answer? Should be easy to create a dummy data frame that works with something like  `df <- data.frame(time = c(rep(12, 10), runif(30, 0, 12)), status = factor(rep(c('healthy', 'relapse'), each = 20)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `add_quantile()` function to provide quantile information annotated on the plot. You can indicate the numeric value where a line segment will be drawn. In this case, for 10% cumulative incidence, you can provide `y_value = .1` as an argument.

Here is a complete example using [trial data](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/trial.html). This dataset includes 200 patients who received Drug A or Drug B as well as the outcome of tumor response to the treatment.

```
library(tidycmprsk)
library(ggsurvfit)

cuminc(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ trt, trial) %>%
  ggcuminc(outcome = "death from cancer") +
  add_risktable(risktable_stats = "n.risk") +
  add_quantile(y_value = .1) +
  scale_ggsurvfit()
```

**Plot**

[image: plot of cumulative incidence with line added at 10% level]

Comment: Great solution to my problem, but how can I see exact value on x-axis?

Comment: @anso_s The values on the x-axis are stored in the plot object. For example, if you store your plot as `p`, by something like: `p <- cuminc(Surv(ttdeath...` then you can extract the values through `layer_data(p, 3)` which contains the coordinates of the line segments added to the figure. In the example above, you will see `x` of 12.52 and 17.42. I hope this helps.